# Transfer speed over network faster than from the server itself Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, python

I have a home server low powered 800mhz 2 cpu running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have attached a 5TB external hard drive USB 3.0 and I get average 30MB+/s read speed using hdparm -t --direct.

My issue is when I'm copying using python shutil.move or mv from the server itself I'm only getting around 1MB or less per second, very rarely goes up. But on this same drive shared over SMB it can go up to 7+MB/s but averge around 4-5MB/s.

What am I missing here? So it seems like the usb is capable of transferring the data since it goes through the same usb connection.

All speed is in megabytes per second.

**Note**: The transfer that is 1MB or less per second is coming from internal drive(SSD) to external drive connected to USB 3.0 same drive that is getting written to from the Network shared using SMB.

Comment: If you move from a partition to another of the same disk you are copying the file and using 2 time the same channel. If you mv in the same partition you are probably _renaming_ the file (really only moving the inode number  from a list to another) so really fast. Can you clarify the transfers you are speaking about?

Comment: The transfer that is 1MB or less per second is coming from internal drive(SSD) to external drive connected to USB 3.0 same drive that is getting written to from the Network shared using SMB.

Comment: Try to copy or move with rsync. It will measure the transfer speed. Use even the option for sparse files. Update your question with the results.

Comment: I just tried with rsync --progress -avz and it's speed average is the same as SMB, around 4-5MB/s. I'll just use rsync in my script. I still tried it with regular mv cp & pythons shutil.move it was 3x slower on average I just measured by time. I measured it also using the size changes on the network drive. Thanks

Comment: It can happen if you have to move or copy in (or from) a single directory a big number of files (thousands): this because in this case the system call below the ls, cp and mv commands is slower and not efficient as the one below rsync. I can suppose there should be the same or a similar reason for phyton script vs samba. How many files we are speaking about?  It happens even for a single big file (not cached)? and for a HUGE one? Give some info about File System types too; they should play their roles too :) .

Comment: They are big files around 2GB+ each. Python script probably uses OS move or copy too reason they are same. The external drive is ext4 format.